# Flasshdevelop: How to bind air to apk

Tags: air, flashdevelop

I am using FlashDevlop to make Android air app.

How can I bind the air SDK to the apk file so the user will not require to download air.

Comment: What you're looking for is called "Captive Runtime". I'm not sure how to do it via FlashDevelop (I use IntelliJ IDEA and FlashBuilder), but that should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: @JoshJanusch tnx, there are plenty of informant available about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the packageApp.bat file.  It is added to the base folder of new FlashDevelop mobile projects.  Execute that and you will see several options for packaging to Android and IOS.  The option you want is #3 (apk-captive-runtime)